# How do I compile with -Xlint:unchecked?

Tags: java, compiler-errors, unchecked

I'm getting a message when I compile my code:

```
Note: H:\Project2\MyGui2.java uses unchecked or unsafe operations.
Note: Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details.
```

How do I recompile with `-Xlint:unchecked`?

Comment: Are you compiling on the command line?  If so, add the `-Xlint:unchecked` to the command line you're executing, just as the message indicates.

Comment: depends on how you run your code.. is it from eclipse? command line?

Comment: What did you do? I have never seen this error message...

Answer (score 58, accepted):

Specify it on the command line for javac:

> javac -Xlint:unchecked

Or if you are using Ant modify your javac target

```
  <javac ...>
    <compilerarg value="-Xlint"/>
  </javac>
```

If you are using Maven, configure this in the [`maven-compiler-plugin`](http://maven.apache.org/plugins/maven-compiler-plugin/examples/pass-compiler-arguments.html)

```
<compilerArgument>-Xlint:unchecked</compilerArgument>
```

Comment: I have maven 3, model 4.0 --  The `<compilerArgument>` goes under `<configuration>` not within the _`<compilerArguments>'_ element.  _Silly me._

Comment: And what about compile inside AOSP? What should I add to Android.mk file?

Answer (score 54):

For **IntelliJ 13.1**, go to <kbd>File</kbd> -> <kbd>Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Project Settings</kbd> -> <kbd>Compiler</kbd> -> <kbd>Java Compiler</kbd>, and on the right-hand side, for `Additional command line parameters` enter `"-Xlint:unchecked"`.

Comment: Thanks. But for 13.1 Community Edition it's at File - Settings - Compiler - Java Compiler, and the field is at the bottom.

Comment: For 14.0.3 this settings page has moved to: File - Settings - Build, Execution, Deployment - Compiler - Java Compiler.

Comment: Not on AndroidStudio, there Compiler options seem to be delivered for *any* compiler, not only Java. Editing **build.gradle** does work.

Comment: In *Android Studio* the compiler options can be found under *File* -> *New Project Settings* -> *Settings for New Projects*. They however seem to **not** be applicable to an existing project.

Answer (score 37):

In gradle project, You can added this compile parameter in the following way:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked"
    }
}
```

Comment: In recent gradle versions the task type `Compile` has been renamed to `JavaCompile`, so it is `tasks.withType(JavaCompile) { ... }`

Comment: I would add that this should go in `allprojects { // ... }`

Comment: Out of all other options, this is the only that worked for me. Thank you so much

Answer (score 23):

I know it sounds weird, but I'm pretty sure this is your problem:

Somewhere in MyGui.java you're using a generic collection without specifying the type. For example if you're using an ArrayList somewhere, you are doing this:

```
List list = new ArrayList();
```

When you should be doing this:

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
```

Comment: Thanks a lot,this helped me!

Comment: This doesn't even attempt to answer the question given.

Answer (score 18):

There is another way for gradle:

```
compileJava {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}
```

Comment: This won't affect the tests for example.

Comment: For Android Studio, this seems to require a bit different approach: `tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
        options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
}`

Comment: for Android Studio 2.1.3 add this to project build.gradle

`allprojects {
    repositories {
        jcenter()
    }
    gradle.projectsEvaluated {
        tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
            options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation"
        }
    }
}`

Answer (score 6):

For Android Studio add the following to your top-level `build.gradle` file within the `allprojects` block

```
tasks.withType(JavaCompile) {
    options.compilerArgs << "-Xlint:unchecked" << "-Xlint:deprecation" 
}
```

Answer (score 3):

In CMD, write:

```
javac -Xlint:unchecked MyGui2.java
```

it will display the list of unchecked or unsafe operations.

Answer (score 3):

If you work with an IDE like NetBeans, you can specify the `Xlint:unchecked`  compiler option in the propertys of your project.

Just go to projects window, right click in the project and then click in `Properties`.

In the window that appears search the `Compiling` category, and in the textbox labeled `Additional Compiler Options` set the `Xlint:unchecked` option.

Thus, the setting will remain set for every time you compile the project.

Answer (score 2):

other way to compile using -Xlint:unchecked through command line

```
javac abc.java -Xlint:unchecked
```

it will show the unchecked and unsafe warnings.

Answer (score 2):

A cleaner way to specify the Gradle compiler arguments follow:

```
compileJava.options.compilerArgs = ['-Xlint:unchecked','-Xlint:deprecation']
```

Comment: This may be *shorter* but it’s not *cleaner*. For one thing, it overrides existing options set elsewhere. For another, it won’t work affect test, as noted in the comments below tarn’s answer. Don’t do this, use xianlinbox’s answer instead.

Answer (score 1):

The answer in 2024:

In the app-level `build.gradle` file add the following code and build your app again.

```
android {
    // ...

        tasks.withType(JavaCompile).tap {
            configureEach {
                options.compilerArgs += '-Xlint:unchecked'
            }
        }

    // ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

FYI getting to these settings has changed for IntelliJ 15, new and improved for even deeper burial!

Now it's: File > Other Settings > Default Settings > 'Build, Execution, Deployment' > Compiler > Java Compiler

And in Additional command line parameters, same as before, write "-Xlint:unchecked".