# How to run SPEC with JOMP?

Tags: java, openmp, specifications

I use [SPEC](http://www.spec.org/) as a tool to measure `java` files running time.
I'm using SPEC2008 which can be downloaded [here](http://www.spec.org/download.html).

I installed spec2008 (`java -jar SPECjvm2008_1_01_setup.jar`) and ran it (`java -jar SPECjvm2008.jar` as written in the README file).
I got a **results** file and a report that everything completed successfully.

Now i need to examine how some changes affect SPEC's running time.

I made the changes in some of SPEC'S files (the java files inside the following folders: `compiler`,`compress`,`crypto`,`derby`).

Now i can't run it again using `java -jar SPECjvm2008.jar` because the changes i made include `jomp` commands (`\\omp parallel for` and such). [JOMP is [OpenMP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/OpenMP) for JAVA]

To compile files with such commands i used to do the following:

First, download [JOMP](http://www2.epcc.ed.ac.uk/computing/research_activities/jomp/download/). Then:

1. change `.java` extension to `.jomp` . Then type:

   ```
   java jomp.compiler.Jomp MyFile
   ```

(now i got a `.java` file)

2. compile to `.class`:

   ```
   javac -classpath YourJompDownloadPath\jomp1.0b.jar; MyFile.java
   ```
3. `java -Djomp.threads=n MyPackage.MyFile`

So i can't do this now because:

1. There are too many files and it would take time changing all extensions to `.jomp`
2. There are too many files and i need to run all of them as a whole (just as SPEC does), but in `JOMP` commands i only know how to run each file independently.

If there's a workaround for #2 then i'll do #1 manually. So i'm especially looking for a solution/workaround for #2.

**edit:**

OK so i made a `.BAT` file only for step 1 (see method [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9885241/changing-all-files-extensions-in-a-folder-with-one-command-on-windows)) because it seems that SPEC has only `.java` files so i'll provide it with `.java` files only. For the 2nd step i think i need to just run SPEC (`java -jar SPECjvm2008.jar`). For the 3rd step, i think instead of normally running SPEC, i need to run it with the parameters in step 3 (`Djomp.threads`). That is:

```
java -Djomp.threads=n -jar SPECjvm2008.jar
```

Now there's a new problem. I get the warning:

```
Recompile with -Xlint:unchecked for details
```

Which was addressed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8215781/how-do-i-compile-with-xlintunchecked). But in that link it's run with `javac` and not `java`. `javac` doesn't recognize the parameter `Djomp.threads` (and `java` doesn't recognize `Xlint`). So i think i'm looking for a way to run a `.jar` file while using `Djomp.threads` and `Xlint`.

Note: running the `.jar` file **SPECjvm2008.jar** eventually runs the `java` files i need. That's why i said "*i'm looking for a way to run a `.jar` file...*"

Comment: This sounds like you are just looking for some `.BAT` files that automate the 3 steps that you mentioned for a given list of `.java` files, is this correct?

Comment: The "edit" is a bit confusing: With `javac`, you *compile* the `.java` files (to create a `.class` file). With `java` you *run* a `.class` file. Only `javac` allows the `Xlint` parameter. But in doubt, you may ignore the warning, because you most likely will not change the `.java` files anyhow.

Comment: Yes you're right. I ignored it, it's nothing serious. It's explained here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/197986/what-causes-javac-to-issue-the-uses-unchecked-or-unsafe-operations-warning

Comment: It's not entirely clear whether the problem is solved now. (But I +1'ed the question, for the research and information that you provided in the question until now)

Comment: It's solved. Where i say "there's a new problem...", it actually isn't a real problem - the comments explain this.