# How to setup IntelliJ IDEA to compile code with a parameter -Xlint:unchecked?

Tags: java, intellij-idea

I read about the -Xlint:unchecked in the Oracle Java tutorial [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/generics/rawTypes.html). And I would like to setup my IDE to inform me about unsafe code. But I faced some troubles trying to accomplish so. But I managed to get a warning message in my Terminal using command:

```
javac GenericsMain.java Box.java -Xlint:unchecked
```

I got such message

> GenericsMain.java:19: warning: [unchecked] unchecked call to addItem(T) 
> as a member of the raw type Box
>   
> rawBox.addItem(8);
>   
> ^
>   
> where T is a type-variable:
>   
> T extends Object declared in class Box
>   
> GenericsMain.java:23: warning: 
>   
> [unchecked] unchecked call to addItem(T) as a member of the raw type Box
>   
> rawBox.addItem(8);
>   
> ^
>   
> where T is a type-variable:
>   
> T extends Object declared in class Box
>   
> 2 warnings

How can I provide this in my IDE? Thank you.

Comment: Look under Settings.  Search for "java compiler"

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Settings (<kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>S</kbd> / <kbd>⌘</kbd><kbd>,</kbd>) > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler > "Additional command line parameters"

This is a per project setting.

[image: screen shot of IntelliJ > Settings/Preferences > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler panel]

To set for new future projects, set the same under File > Other Settings > Default Settings

[image: screen shot of IntelliJ > File > Other Settings > Default Settings > Build, Execution, Deployment > Compiler > Java Compiler >]

More details at: https://www.jetbrains.com/help/idea/java-compiler.html

Comment: Tor clarify… The key is to understand that IntelliJ merges project-specific settings with app-wide settings (or "Preferences" on macOS). Look for faint text at top of settings panel noting “For current project”. I find this merging to be confusing, but *c’est la vie*.

Comment: This answer is only correct if you are using IntelliJ "native" projects, for the Ant and Maven answer see https://stackoverflow.com/a/8215793/3610458